# Hour over Hour calculation in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I currently have a dataset where I have date column, hour column and sale column.

Edit 2:  I have added a sample dataset with an additional column
https://ufile.io/dq2av

```
date | Hour | Sales

1/1    1      1

1/1    2      2

1/1    3      3
```

what I would like to do is a calculated field so it is more like

```
date | Hour | Sales | Last Hour
1/1    1      1       0

1/1    2      2       1

1/1    3      3       2
```

Does anyone have any experience for this?

Update #4:  I have solved this with the combine help of Joe and Marc.
I created the Sequence column

```
Sequence = FORMAT(Sheet1[Click_Date], "General Number")+(.1*Sheet1[dtClickHour])
```

FYI - If you have a large amount of records, please extend the .1 to .00001 because it will round up to a whole number in the sequence

Index

```
Index = RANKX(Sheet1, Sheet1[Sequence],,ASC,DENSE)
```

Cake Clicks Last Hour

```
Cake Clicks Last Hour = if(Sheet1[dtClickHour]=0, 0, SUMX(FILTER(Sheet1,Sheet1[Index]=earlier(Sheet1[Index])-1),Sheet1[Cake Clicks]))
```

The only extra step I could from here was change the calculation of Cake Click Last Hours to Average.

Comment: Is your Last Hour column the value from the Hour column from the previous hour? Or is it the value from the Sales column? (It might help with less ambiguous numbers)

Comment: I would want the 1PM sales numbers in the 2PM Last Hour column so if you look side by side the last hour sales is in the current hours "Last Hour numbers"

Comment: How do you see multiple days being handled? Are they self contained (i.e. the first hour of the day will always have a "0" for last hour)?

Comment: It would be one day only (Filter to today date).  I anticipate that the max hour would have 0 in that value

Comment: The result in your Index column is questioning. When I use your formula with the data you show, I get 1, 2, 3, etc... Can you share a more complete sample set of data (all rows and columns)?

Comment: I am using the much smaller dataset that is attached in the main body https://ufile.io/dq2av

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer @Joe provided worked for me with your information above.

I started with this (which was named Table3):

[image]

And added a new column using

```
`Cake Clicks Last Hour = CALCULATE(
IF(ISBLANK(MAX(Table3[Cake Clicks])), 0, MAX(Table3[Cake Clicks])),
FILTER(Table3,
    Table3[Click_Date] = EARLIER(Table3[Click_Date]) &&
    Table3[dtClickHour] = EARLIER(Table3[dtClickHour]) - 1
)
)`
```

...which is Joe's code edited with your latest info (e.g., your column's names).

*If that works for you, please select his answer.*

Otherwise, here is another alternative that might help you. I started with the above table and derived this:

[image]

Here's how:

1. I added a new column called "Sequence" to give me a sequence count that accounts for both the date and the hour: `Sequence = FORMAT(Table3[Click_Date], "General Number")+(.1*Table3[dtClickHour])`
2. I added a new column called "Index" so I'd have something to identify record numbers: `Index = COUNTROWS(FILTER(Table3,Table3[Sequence]<earlier(Table3[Sequence])))`
3. I added a new column called "Cake Clicks Last Hour" that used the Index to determine which value to pull: `Cake Clicks Last Hour = if(Table3[dtClickHour]=0, 0, sumx(FILTER(Table3,Table3[Index]=earlier(Table3[Index])-1),Table3[Cake Clicks]))`

Comment: I believe my biggest challenge is the assumption only these two column exists in the datasets.  There are currently 20 other dimensions and ten other metrics.  When I made it just Click_Date, dtClickHour, Cake Click only, Joe's Code works beautifully.  Now when I start adding dimensions to that same feed, it gets the crazy numbers again

Comment: @JuniorFlip - I've added an additional column to that table and added a related table, and I'm still getting to correct values using my original formula (edited for column names).

Comment: I have blanks for the Last Cake Clicks column.  I followed all of the formulas, remap correctly and created all as column.  I will put the image up above

Comment: I believe I have solve it.  I have change the INDEX formula to Index = RANKX(Sheet1, Sheet1[Sequence],,ASC,DENSE) and I have updated the Cake Clicks Last Hour to Average versus sums

Comment: You got blanks because your index skips numbers. I don't know why your index skips numbers. It doesn't do that for me. I get sequential numbers when I set up my table *exactly* like yours shown above and I use `Index = COUNTROWS(FILTER(Sheet1,Sheet1[Sequence]<earlier(Sheet1[Sequence])))`. The "Last Cake Clicks" column formula first looks at the index of the current row, then finds the row with an index one number less. In your case, there is no index 3, so when it starts from the row with index 4 and looks for index 4 minus 1, which is 3, there is no index 3 to find.

Comment: Glad you got it working. ...But I am perplexed why neither Joe's solution nor mine worked for you directly, as they did for us.

Answer (score 1):

Updated formula based on additional information.

To get the last hour's click number into the current hour's row, add a new column with this formula.

```
Cake Clicks Last Hour = CALCULATE(
    IF(ISBLANK(SUM(Clicks[Cake Clicks])), 0, SUM(Clicks[Cake Clicks])),
    FILTER(Clicks,
        Clicks[Click_Date] = EARLIER(Clicks[Click_Date]) &&
        Clicks[dtClickHour] = EARLIER(Clicks[dtClickHour]) - 1
    )
)
```

[image: Results]

Comment: Does it matter if there are additional dimension in the data because I am getting a higher rollout

Comment: What do you mean by "higher rollout"?

Comment: The screenshot above is showing inflated numbers when using the formula. I use the above formula it may be record count